# Getting GNU Make and NMake to use different makefiles by default

Tags: makefile, nmake

I want a project to be buildable with both GNU Make (on Linux) and NMake (on Windows). Obviously, I can have the makefiles called `Makefile` and `Nmakefile` and build by using `make` and `nmake /F Nmakefile` respectively. Is there a pair of names such that `make` and `nmake` *without* `-f`/`/F` options work?

According to documentation, NMake looks for `.mak` files, so I've tried to use `Makefile.mk` and `Nmakefile.mak`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the man page of GNU make, it will first look for a file called `GNUmakefile`.

Answer (score 2):

from man make:

> Normally you should call your makefile
>   either makefile or Makefile.  (We
>   recommend Makefile because it  appears
>   prominently  near  the beginning of a
>   directory listing, right near other
>   important files such as README.)  The
>   first name checked, GNUmakefile, is
>   not recommended for most makefiles. 
>   You should use this name if you have a
>   makefile  that  is  specific to GNU
>   make, and will not be understood by
>   other versions of make.  If makefile
>   is `-', the standard input is read.

so call your gnu Makefile `GNUmakefile`